# ruby rails test case failing but real app works

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, url-routing, rake-test, ruby-test

So here's a strange problem: When I start my local rails app and browse to http://localhost:3000/static_pages/help I can see the page I created there.
However, the test case that I wrote says otherwise.

**static_pages_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get help" do
    puts static_pages_help_url
    puts static_pages_help_path
    get static_pages_help_url
    assert_response :success
  end    

end
```

It fails with this error, Output of $bin/rake test:

```
 Running:

..http://test.host/static_pages/help
/static_pages/help
E

Finished in 0.466745s, 8.5700 runs/s, 4.2850 assertions/s.

  1) Error.

StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"http://test.host/static_pages/help", :controller=>"static_pages"}
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

Here is **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'static_pages/home'

  get "static_pages/help"
end
```

and here is the **static_pages_controller.rb**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end
end
```

and these two files

```
app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb
app/views/static_pages/help.html.erb
```

exist, as I can also see them when navigating to /static_pages/help in my browser. I've searched the web for hours, no clue.

```
$ rails --version
Rails 4.2.7.1
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
```

I must be missing something. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're writing a controller spec, the parameter to a `GET` should be the `action`(controller method). But you're passing a URL. If you look at the error message, you can find that `"http://test.host/static_pages/help"` was passed into `action`. So, pass the name of the controller method as a `symbol` rather than the URL. Try

```
get :help
```

Note that `help` is the controller action.

However if you're interested in writing an `integration` test, you should inherit from `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` rather than `ActionController::TestCase`. So, your spec should look aomething like this.

```
class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get home" do
    get static_pages_home_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get static_pages_help_url
    assert_response :success
  end        
end
```

To learn more about integration and controller tests, see http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/1/30/unit-vs-functional-vs-integration.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer!
What completely puzzles me is this: Why would the author of this page https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#code-default_controller_test
write his test like that? While in fact it doesn't work! It has cost me hours...

Comment: @Codekid, don't under-estimate Hartl. He knows his stuffs. The problem is that if you look at the example code given by Hartl, its actually an `integration test` while what you're trying to do is `controller spec`. See the class signature of Hartl's code and yours. Your `StaticPagesControllerTest is inheriting from `ActionController::TestCase` while his implementation is inheriting from `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`. In simple terms, Hartl's code tries to visit the url and see if the response is a success. But a controller spec is different.

Comment: This answers what I actually wanted to know. Now it's all clear. Thank you so much.